# How to listen to a specific value change in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data structure is the following: compliments/received/{uid}/{complimentId}
[image]

I would like to listen to changes on compliments/received/{uid}/{complimentId}/updatedAt

My code is:

```
firebase.database().ref('compliments/received/' + currentUser._id).on('child_changed', (snap) => {
  console.log('update in action', snap.val())
  snap.ref.child('updatedAt').on('value', () => onUpdate(snap))
});
```

The problem:
This listener triggers when I update any field on the given database path, eg: when I set "seen" from 0 to 1. I would like to trigger this listener only when the updatedAt field's value changes.

What I tried so far:

```
firebase.database().ref('compliments/received/' + currentUser._id).on('child_changed', (snap) => {
  console.log('update in action', snap.val())
  snap.ref.child('updatedAt').on('child_changed', () => onUpdate(snap))
});
```

This listener does not trigger when I change the updatedAt field's value.

Any recommendations are welcome!
Thanks!

Solution as per Ali's answer:

```
firebase.database().ref('compliments/received/' + currentUser._id).on('child_added', (snap) => {
    console.log('add in action', snap.val());
    firebase.database().ref('compliments/received/' + currentUser._id)
    .child(snap.key).child('updatedAt').on('value', async () => {
      const newSnap = await firebase.database().ref('compliments/received/' + currentUser._id)
      .child(snap.key).once('value')
      onUpdate(newSnap)
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

checkout this

```
firebase.database().ref('compliments/received/' + currentUser._id).on('child_added', (snap) =>
{
    console.log('add in action', snap.val());
    firebase.database().ref('compliments/received/' + currentUser._id)
    .child(snap.key).child('updatedAt').on('value', (updateSnap) => onUpdate(updateSnap))
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem, since I would like to be subscribed to compliments/received/$userId/$complimentId when I load my application. The result of this code is that I get no triggers on updatedAt's value change.

Comment: when do you load the app do you have the value of `complimentId`

Comment: Actually I want to be subscribed to all of the compliments under the 'compliments/received/$userId' That part works, so I get the console log of 'update in action', when I change the compliment. The part that is not working is to listen to the 'updatedAt' property inside of the compliment, and only in that case trigger the 'onUpdate()' callback.

Comment: The problem is, that I would like to be able to listen to changes on already existing compliments. I do have a listener for new compliments already, that is working fine, basically the same as you wrote. The current goal would be to listen to every added compliment & every existing compliment's updatedAt field.

Answer (score 0):

```html
const { getDatabase, ref, onChildAdded } = require('firebase/database');

    const db = getDatabase();
    
    onChildAdded(ref(db, 'compliments/received/' + currentUser._id), (snapshot) => {
        
        console.log(snapshot.val())
        
    })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).