# Firebase Realtime Database Property Listener

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some data like so: `leaderboards/board/{board id}/{child properties}`

[image: Screen capture of example data in Realtime Database]

I have an added listener for boards, like so:

```
const boardRef = firebase.database().ref('leaderboards/board');
boardRef.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    // handle data
});
```

That part works fine. I then later want to listen to just a specific property on a board, to see if it changes. I do *not* want to listen to all child changes on the board, as a couple of the children can change really frequently and we don't want to be handling that much data except when needed (a certain app state). So, I tried this:

```
const endedRef = firebase.database().ref('leaderboards/board/123/ended');
endedRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    // handle data
});
```

However, when I update the 'ended' property in Firebase, the listener isn't called. It's only called when I first add the listener (so it appears to be hooked up properly) but then not when the property is changed. What's the proper way to solve this?

This post is similar, but as I'm already trying a 'value' listener on the property, seems to either not be a fix or not work for my data: [How to listen to a specific value change in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48484800/how-to-listen-to-a-specific-value-change-in-firebase)

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Your code looks correct, and in my experience should fire when the `ended` property of `123` changes. If will in that scenario fire with `snapshot` being the new value of the `ended` property, not a snapshot of the entire board. Is that not what you're seeing? If so, can you show what you get in the snapshot in the callback?

Comment: I only ever get a snapshot when the listener is added, not when the value is changed, which is the problem. But the snapshot is indeed just the ended property, as I'd expect: `false`

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure why that would be. Can you set up a repro of the problem on a site like jsbin or stackblitz, so that I can have a look?

Comment: Haha well I'm glad you asked me to do that... I couldn't repro in jsbin, so realized it was an issue elsewhere in my code. (Turns out, I was adding the listener inside a vector object and due to code accesses, copies of the object were getting destroyed, which was removing my listener.)

It's working now, thanks for helping me get there! :)

Comment: Good to hear you found the cause Miranda 
It's one of the reason we often ask for a [minimal/isolated repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was related to something specific in my codebase, causing my listener removal to get triggered just after getting added. So if you're having a similar issue, check where you remove the listener!

Comment: If you have found the answer yourself, be sure to accept your answer for some reputation points!

Comment: Yeah I'm planning to, I just apparently have to wait a day.